# Calculating Churn Model

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to parse the customers whom we did business with in the preceding year(2017) but now this year(2018). How can I get the names of the customers who churned out on us in 2018. I am using SSMS 2016.

Sample data:

```
Client_ID    Client_Name     Order_Date           Revenue         
   214         ssms            2/4/2017             10000
   344         oracle          2/14/2017            9000
   754         postgresql      7/17/2017            15000
   154         toad            9/27/2017            14852
   854         teradata        12/14/2017           54111
   654         sybase          10/25/2017           85477
   214         ssms            3/25/2018            25000
   854         teradata        5/14/2018            35000
   654         sybase          10/24/2018           45000
  .........................................

select client_id, client_name
from my_table
where year(order_date) = 2017
and year(order_date) <> 2018
```

The above query returns 2017 customers but there is no telling whether 2018 numbers were filtered beforehand or not.

Results requested:

```
Client_ID         Client_Name
  754             postgresql
  344             oracle
  154             toad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exists as

```
select client_id, client_name
from T tt
where year(order_date) = 2017
      and not exists(select 1 from t where client_id = tt.client_id and year(order_date) = 2018)
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=30c23e8a089d72c850a05288c238da4b)**

You can also use `IN()` as

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE Order_Date >= '2017-01-01'
      AND
      Order_Date <= '2017-12-31'
      AND
      Client_ID NOT IN(
        SELECT Client_ID
        FROM T
        WHERE Order_Date >= '2018-01-01'
              AND
              Order_Date <= '2018-12-31'
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t1.client_id,
       t1.client_name
       FROM my_table t1
       WHERE t1.order_date >= '2017-01-01'
             AND t1.order_date < '2018-01-01'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM my_table t2
                                    WHERE t2.client_id = t1.client_id
                                          AND t2.order_date >= '2018-01-01'
                                          AND t2.order_date < '2019-01-01');
```

You may also want to rewrite the conditions to no longer use the `year()` function on the `order_date` column but a comparison to a range so that indexes can be used for the column.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this task I generally use the 'having' clause although if you have a large amount of data to process you might need something more efficient.

```
select client_name, max(year(order_date)) as final_year from my_table group by client_name having max(year(order_date)) = 2018
```

The above will return all clients with the last order being in 2018.

Including an additional 'having' condition such as:

```
and min(year(order_date)) < 2018
```

Will exclude clients who had their first transaction in 2018.

Hopefully this is sufficient for your purposes.

*apologies for not using your exact schema names etc*

Comment: Thanks, `max`will get the new customers as well as old for 2018 but what would `min` do again?

Comment: 'min' can be used to exclude clients based on the earliest transaction date. For example, if you wanted to find clients who became clients for the first time in 2017, continued through 2018 and did not continue with your business in 2019. Then `min(year(order_date)) = 2017` and `max(year(order_date)) = 2018` - I only included it for completeness which may have been misleading. I think 'max' will suffice for your requirement.